# Scala return object of unknown type

Tags: scala, object, return, instance

How can I save an object of unknown type in Scala and return it?

I have a couple of classes that are all instantiated from the same class like this

```
class And(lhs: ExprTree, rhs: ExprTree) extends ExprTree
class Or(lhs: ExprTree, rhs: ExprTree) extends ExprTree
```

and a function that needs to return an instance of said classes (i.e. `And(lhs, rhs)` but I have no prior knowledge which). I also need to store an instance of `And()` or `Or()` without prior knowledge which one it is.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is, but it seems to me that you're looking for something like [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: By "i.e.", do you mean "e.g."?

Comment: Yes, I mean for example ;) Sorry

Comment: What signature for your function have you tried so far? Why can't you simply return an instance of `ExprTree` (i.e. `def f():ExprTree`) ?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on your use-case?  "have no prior knowledge which". OK but what will tell you which you have to return?

Comment: I followed @hasumedic advice and rewrote my code to use pattern matching which now works.
I can now use the signature `def f(): ExprTree` which didn't work with my previous code.

Answer (score 0):

```
val expr: ExprTree = ???
```

will give you an identifier which could take on the value of either an `And` or an `Or`.

Similarly,

```
def (...): ExprTree = ???
```

will give you a function which will return a value of either `And` or `Or` (assuming some appropriate parameters, represented here by ...).

This answer seems far too simple and obvious. But it also seems to satisfy what I think is your request.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe he needs an instance of `And` or an instance of `Or`. Getting an instance of `ExprTree` hides that information. If you get a `Vehicle`, you don't know if it's a `Car`, a `Truck` or a `Bicycle`.  What you are saying is trivial knowledge of inheritance in OOP and since he's using `extends` I believe he already knows that ;)

Comment: @slouc, I wouldn't be so certain. It won't be the first SO question to which the answer was simple polymorphism...